# How to save UserDetails before logging out in Xamarin.Forms (Android/IOS)

Tags: php, xamarin.forms, logout

I don't know if the logout proces like the code beneath is correct but i would like to save all the user changes before a user hits the logout button. Is there a way to do this? Have you some example links or some php scripts that could do this?

```
private async void LogoutButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var res = await DisplayAlert("Would you like to logout?", null, "Yes", "Cancel");

        if(res == true)
        {
            Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage()); //login page
        }
    }
```

Comment: Save changes where exactly? Remember that user can just kill the app, and your logout logic will be omitted.

Comment: So I would like that when a setting is changed by the user that the app remembers it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at [Xamarin.Essentials: Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android)

The **Preferences** class helps to store application preferences in a key/value store.

you just need save data before you logout like:

```
Preferences.Set("my_key", "my_value");
```

and get the data :

```
var myValue = Preferences.Get("my_key", "default_value");
```